Blend mode is not working on IOS browsers
I'm experiencing an issue with the CSS property mix-blend-mode: color; on iOS devices. It works correctly on Windows and Android, but it doesn’t seem to have any effect on iOS browsers. If anyone has a solution or a workaround, I’d appreciate it! Here’s the relevant code snippet:
 <div className="banner-main-container">
            <video
                muted
                loop
                autoPlay
                playsInline
                src={getImageUrl(
                    bannersList?.[0]?.attributes.video.data?.attributes?.url
                )}
            />

            <div className="overlay-with-opacity"></div>
            <div className="overlay-blend-mode"></div>
</div>
.overlay-blend-mode {
        @apply absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full;
         mix-blend-mode: color;
        background: #2c263f;
    }
 .overlay-with-opacity {
        @apply absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full opacity-80;
        background: #2c263f;
    }

I applied mix-blend-mode: color; to an overlay element, expecting it to blend the overlay color with the background content on all devices. This approach worked as expected on Windows and Android browsers, creating a color overlay effect. However, on iOS devices, it had no effect— the color blend didn’t apply, and the overlay simply displayed as a solid color.
I anticipated a consistent color blend effect across all platforms, but the lack of support on iOS led to a discrepancy in the design, where the expected overlay blending effect was missing entirely.

What are you trying to overlay on? I ask because according to https://caniuse.com/?search=mix-blend-mode Safari does not support color if e.g. an svg is involved.

Could you create a small runnable snippet that shows the problem? It makes it much easier for us to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
